# Fuzzy string comparison with google-diff-match-patch?

Tags: java, string-matching

What is the appropriate way to make fuzzy string matching using google-diff-match-patch API. I would like it if I can see sample usage of it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the demo:

http://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_match.html

Source:

http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/source/browse/trunk/demos/demo_match.html

Comment: I went through this and ended up creating a wrapper library to help with the "presentation work" needed to use `diff_match_patch`: https://github.com/arnab/jQuery.PrettyTextDiff